# What is the proper way to respond if someone thanks us by saying 'Jazakallah Khair'?

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices

**What is the proper way to respond if someone thanks us by saying 'Jazakallah Khair'?**

Do I say

> wa ʾiyyākum (وَإِيَّاكُمْ‎)

or do I say

> "wa ʾantum fa-jazākumu-llāhu khayran" (وَأَنْتُمْ فَجَزَاكُمُ ٱللَّٰهُ
> خَيْرًا‎)

***Or is there a third more preferred way (as per Sahih Hadiths)?***

Comment: This isn't a religious question... you reply as you want, in arabic, right?

Comment: @Muslimpro56 Most people who say Jazakallah Khair do so with an intention of gaining good deeds. So in a way it is a religious question but definitely not a fard act.